# How can I authenticate with Artifactory in Go?

Tags: go, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I cannot really make any sense of the extremely terse documentation - my use case is I have a file at a known URL in Artifactory and I want to download it. For this I need to authenticate with Artifactory.

I have this code:

```
func authenticateToArtifactory() string {

rtDetails := auth.NewArtifactoryDetails()
rtDetails.SetUrl(artifactoryURL)
fmt.Printf("Artifactory login name....\n")
var userName string
fmt.Scanln(&userName)
fmt.Printf("Artifactory password....\n")
var passWord string
fmt.Scanln(&passWord)
rtDetails.SetUser(userName)
rtDetails.SetPassword(passWord)
apiKey := rtDetails.GetAPIKey()
fmt.Printf("API key is %s\n", apiKey)
return apiKey
}
```

But it doesn't work - to be honest this isn't a surprise as there isn't even a getAPIKey() call defined - but I really don't know what to do here.

What's the right way to do this?

**Edit**: From reading around I *think* I might have to use a http client for this - ie I cannot authenticate with Artifactory directly: is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of frustration and trial and error, I think I have this working - the documentation is shockingly poor, so I do hope this helps someone else.

Here's a basic Set up... (getting all these trailing '/' in is essential and as far as I can see *none* of this is documented):

```
var artifactoryURL = "https://your.remote.server/artifactory/"

rtDetails := auth.NewArtifactoryDetails()
rtDetails.SetUrl(artifactoryURL)
fmt.Printf("Artifactory login name....\n")
var userName string
userName = [some way of getting user name eg via command line]
fmt.Printf("Artifactory password....\n")
var passWord string
passWord = [some way of getting artifactory password eg via command line]
rtDetails.SetUser(userName)
rtDetails.SetPassword(passWord)

artifactoryHTTP := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{}}
serviceConfig, err := config.NewConfigBuilder().SetServiceDetails(rtDetails).SetDryRun(false).SetHttpClient(artifactoryHTTP).Build()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
rtManager, errSC := artifactory.New(serviceConfig)
if errSC != nil {
    panic(errSC)
}
params := services.NewDownloadParams()
params.Pattern = "[repo_name]/path/to/your/file/your_file"
_, _, err = rtManager.DownloadFiles(params)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", err.Error())
    panic(err)
}
```

The repo name is the first bit of the file's URL after artifactory: eg

http://my.server.address/artifactory/repo_name/blah/blah/blah/file_I_want.tar.gz